# DVD malicious code

Tags: dvd, iso-image

As I know there is not just burned data on the DVD. I read that there is something like file structure and volume information included on the ISO 9660 format. 
My question is - is it possible to integrate malicious code or a virus into this ISO 9660 data?

Answer (score 1):

ISO 9660 DVD's have a proper file system, containing files and folders. You can put anything on a DVD.

So yes, someone can easily put very malicious programs on a DVD. You need to know where it came from before you put one in your computer, and even then make sure you have an anti-virus program and that it's quite up-to-date.

Comment: Probably the easiest way this could happen would be an autorun type of thing like Sony's rootkit - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_BMG_copy_protection_rootkit_scandal - though I haven't heard of any company actually doing this.